# How to allow both/either public key and/or password authentication

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I am trying to get Komodo to connect to a remote server. However, as I understand it, Komodo doesn't support public ssh keys. I edited the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file and set both

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

However, when I try to connect I keep getting the following message:

```
Error: 'Remote SSH server does not allow password authentication. Allowed types are: u'publickey''
```

How can I set the server up so that it accepts both types of authentication? Note: I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you restart the sshd service after making the change ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration looks ok. Once you have changed the sshd_config file, you need to restart sshd so that it can read the new config.

Answer (score 1):

Usualy the key and the password auth are enabled by default. Check this options are anabled (probably they have been disabled during key-auth configuration):

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes # default
PasswordAuthentication yes # default
UsePAM yes # default
```

if this will not help, try to ssh with -v (-vv or -vvv) option.

And the dummy question: was the sshd restarted after changing configuration?